# MySQL Syntax Error when selecting FROM match

Tags: php, mysql

I'm getting a syntax error with this block of code, and I have no idea why. Here is the specific error itself:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'match ORDER BY id DESC' at line 1

Here is the PHP code block:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM match ORDER BY id DESC";
$res = mysqli_query($dbCon, $sql);
```

Comment: match is a keyword...try to ignore

Answer (score 3):

`MATCH` is a reserved keyword in mysql: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/keywords.html

To make your code working change your query to:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `match` ORDER BY id DESC";
```